# Django - AJAX POST to API not working but no errors

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to post data to my Django Rest Framework API, I have a GET request which works. The POST request does not work and the error function of the AJAX call is fired. I cant seem to see why it wont work, perhaps my CSRF or CORS headers are incorrect?

**main.js**

```
$(function () {

  var $items = $('#items');
  var $description = $('#description');
  var $price = $('#price');

   $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: '/api',
     success: function(items) {
       console.log(items)
       $.each(items,function(i, item){
         $items.append('<li> '+ item.pk +', '+ item.Description +', '+ item.Price +'</li>');
       });
     },
     error: function() {
       alert('Error Loading Items');
     }
   });

   $('#add-item').on('click', function() {

     var order = {
       description: $description.val(),
       price: $price.val(),
     };

     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
       url: '127.0.0.1:8000/api/',

       data: order,

       success: function(newItem) {
         $items.append('<li> '+ newItem.Description +', '+ newItem.Price +'</li>');
       },
       error: function() {
         console.log(order)
       }
     });

   });


});
```

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Description
```

**Serializers Views.py**

```
class ItemListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Post request require X-CSRF-TOKEN header set with correct token - that's why `get` request was passing (I assume), but `post` is not.

You cannot use django template language (`{{ csrf_token }}`) in javascript file, since it will not render to actual token - it will just pass string literal `'{{ csrf_token }}'`.

You can acquire actual token like this, with help of [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#ajax), assuming [authentication is set by default](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication):

```js
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getCookie('csrftoken'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    url: '127.0.0.1:8000/api/',

    data: order,

    success: function (newItem) {
        $items.append('<li> ' + newItem.Description + ', ' + newItem.Price + '</li>');
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log(order)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ive tried your solution. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. very unsure what the issue could be.

Comment: Check via your browser developer console on what answer does your server response with. That will help understand what's wrong here.